# pytubeライブラリを使用した際に表示される "<Stream: ...>" はなんという型の値ですか？そしてそれをリストにしたい。

Tags: python, python3

[pytube](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/)というライブラリを使用したPythonコードを実行したらこのような値が出てきたのですがこれってなんと言う型の値なのでしょうか？
辞書でもないしリストでもないです。

また、この中身をリストに変えたりは可能でしょうか？

```
<Stream: itag="22" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.64001F" acodec="mp4a.40.2">
<Stream: itag="43" mime_type="video/webm" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp8.0" acodec="vorbis">
<Stream: itag="18" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.42001E" acodec="mp4a.40.2">
<Stream: itag="36" mime_type="video/3gpp" res="240p" fps="30fps" vcodec="mp4v.20.3" acodec="mp4a.40.2">
<Stream: itag="17" mime_type="video/3gpp" res="144p" fps="30fps" vcodec="mp4v.20.3" acodec="mp4a.40.2">
<Stream: itag="137" mime_type="video/mp4" res="1080p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.640028">
<Stream: itag="248" mime_type="video/webm" res="1080p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp9">
```

リストにしたい理由はこの中から画質の良い順番に並べ変えて取り出せないかなと考えているからです。

vars()の関数を使えば辞書型では取り出せるような気がします。

Githubのページをみて以下のコードを実行すれば

```
>>> yt.streams.filter(progressive=True).order_by('resolution').desc().all()
```

一番画質のいいやつが取れるような気がするのですが'resolution'の部分をbitrateって変えると画質が低いものになるのでしょうか？

If you need to optimize for a specific feature, such as the "highest resolution" or "lowest average bitrate":

英訳が苦手でgoogle翻訳使ったのですがいまいち自信がないです。
.order_byの他の機能なんかもあるのでしょうか？

Comment: はいそうです！pytube使っています。

Comment: [pytube.Stream 型(クラス)](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/blob/master/pytube/streams.py#L26)という事になります。また、インスタンスの内容を表示しているのは [pytube.Stream.__repr__() メソッド](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/blob/master/pytube/streams.py#L304)です。

Comment: この中身をリストに変えたりは可能でしょうか？

Comment: どういうリストにしたいかが解らないと具体的な回答は難しいかも知れませんね。リストにしたい理由も想像が難しいです。

Comment: 回答は出ているのではないでしょうか？「この`<Stream: …>`の型の名前は？」→「`pytube.Stream`型(クラス)という事になります。」。追記によって質問の内容が変わっているかと思います…。「別の型に変換したい～」は具体的な想定値や環境、状況を添えて、別質問を立ててはどうでしょう？

Comment: https://github.com/nficano/pytube#behold-a-perfect-balance-of-simplicity-versus-flexibility に書かれているサンプルコードを参考にすれば、画質の良い順番に並べ変える事は可能かと思います。